# Get current url without parameters

Tags: magento-1.9, template, geturl

How can I get current url without utm parameters for example? I need this in phtml templates. 
Thank you.

EDIT

EXAMPLE:

From url

```
www.example.com/post?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=campaign
```

I need to get only

```
www.example.com/post
```

Answer (score 8):

The cleanest way to do that is:

```
echo $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_use_rewrite' => true, '_forced_secure' => true));
```

- The first parameter `'*/*/*'` means that you stay on the same module/controller/action
- The second parameter is an array of options

The option `'_use_rewrite'` let you keep the rewrited url, for example:

`/my-category/my-product-url-key/` instead of `/catalog/product/view/id/456/category/123`

The option `'_forced_secure'` will be useful for website having SSL enabled.

There are other options that you can find documented here:
http://dltr.org/blog/magento/418/Magento-get-url-with-or-without-parameters

Comment: How can you do that with a specific store wise?

Answer (score 2):

It's much more simple. You can simply get the original path info.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo();
```

Comment: the return for this, for example "checkout_cart_index"

Answer (score 1):

You can get current url without parameters

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$urlWithoutParameters = $this->getBaseUrl() . $request->getRouteName() .DS. $request->getControllerName() .DS. $request->getActionName();
```

You can get current url like this

```
 echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

if this is not work than you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504608/request-string-without-get-arguments-in-php)

Hope this will help you

Comment: That isnt exactly what I was looking for. For example: at this url `www.example.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=campaign` I need to get only `www.example.com/`

Comment: You want to domain name only ri8?

Comment: Bad example, sorry. I want to get rid of the parameters.

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 1):

I am using

```
$urlWithoutParameters = Mage::getBaseUrl() . $request->getRouteName() .DS. $request->getControllerName() .DS. $request->getActionName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get URL without any parameters,

```
 $this->getUrl("*/adminhtml_report_brands/index", array("_current" => false))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using my application under `/magento` directory. This helped me to get URL without any parameter.

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getBasePath().Mage::app()->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo(); ?>
```

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

**To get this (current) URL in your module:**

```
$currentUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
//Gives: http://loca.lho.st/review/product/list/id/27/name/sony
```

**To get current URL parameters:**

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); //all the parameters
//Gives: Array ( [id] => 27 [name] => sony )
$param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name'); //parameter "name"
//Gives: sony
```

**To get only URL without parameters:**

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$urlWithoutParameters = $this->getBaseUrl() . $request->getRouteName() .DS. $request->getControllerName() .DS. $request->getActionName();
//Gives: http://loca.lho.st/review/product/list
```

Comment: How can we deal with category url like https://example.com/democategory?p=2&spo=2